# Find the Maclaurin seris for $f(x)= 1/(1+4/5x)^3$

Tags: calculus

I am having a few problems with this as the all of $(1+4/5x)$ is raised to the power of $3$ rather than just the $x$ term.

Answer (score 3):

Let's write:
$$\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{4}{5x}\right)^3}=\left(\frac{5x}{5x+4}\right)^3=125x^3\frac{1}{(5x+4)^3}$$
Now notice that we have:
$$\frac{1}{(5x+4)^3}=\frac{1}{50}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{1}{5x+4}$$
I think you can take it from here.